# calling xacro:macro from within xacro:macro

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can I include and call an xacro:macro from within an xacro:macro?

alternatively, can I pass a variable to an xacro if it is not an xacro:macro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33806/calling-xacro:macro-from-within-xacro:macro/) by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-05-11**:
For question2, if it is not a xacro:macro, what is it?

**Comment by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) on 2012-12-21**:
xacro:macro refers to an xacro that contains a macro. In my answer below, I include an xacro file "irb_5400_macro.xacro" that contains the macro "irb_5400". Then I call that xacro:macro from THIS file. An xacro file can also just contain a set of commands, or even constants (like an include file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For question 1, yes you can. Recursive macros are allowed.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question #1 - Yes, macros can be recursive. My error was that I put the includes for the referenced xacro files under the xacro:macro name="..." line.

The correct way is:

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <include filename="$(find abb_common)/urdf/irb_5400_macro.xacro" /> 
  <xacro:macro name="generate_robot" params="robot_name" >
    <xacro:irb_5400 prefix="${robot_name}"/>
```

Make sure all the includes are **above the macro declaration!**

---

Originally posted by [dsolomon](https://answers.ros.org/users/2369/dsolomon/) with karma: 253 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1